# jquery datepicker highlight

Tags: jquery, datepicker, highlight

I am trying to highlight the date for  corresponding events in the database. My code is not working properly and in the datepicker only the date for the last event in the database is highlighted all the other events are not getting highlighted.please help me to find a solution.

```
 var row;          
      var title1 ;
      var date1;
         var events;

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate:0,

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var result = [true, '', null];
    var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
        return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
    });

    if (matching.length) {
        result = [true, 'highlight', null];
    }
    return result;
},
onSelect: function(dateText) {
    var date,
        selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
        i = 0,
        event = null;

    /* Determine if the user clicked an event: */
    while (i < events.length && !event) {
        date = events[i].Date;

        if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
            event = events[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (event) {
        /* If the event is defined, perform some action here; show a tooltip, navigate to a URL, etc. */
        alert(event.Title);
    }
}
    }); 
});

 $(function () 
  {

$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
  {
    for (var i in rows)
    {
      row = rows[i];          

      title1 = row[0];
      date1 = row[1];

       events = [    
 { Title:"title1", Date: new Date(date1) }, 

];

    } 
  } 
});
  });
```

Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Just try the code below, I have assumed your events array as static

```
<script>
     var row;          
     var events = [    
                    { "Title":"title1", "Date": new Date("15/March/2014") },
                    { "Title":"title2", "Date": new Date("16/March/2014") },
                    { "Title":"title3", "Date": new Date("17/March/2014") },
                    { "Title":"title4", "Date": new Date("20/March/2014") }, 
                  ];

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate:0,

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var result = [true, '', null];
            var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
                if(event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf())
                    result = [true, 'highlight', event.Title];
            });
            return result;
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: When i try to retrieve data from the database only the last row is highlighted means the last date . What should i change to make it work...? i am unable to find the error..

Comment: Can you cross check the array of the events that you are returning via ajax, may be that will be causing a problem to you ? Also please make the ajax call before the datepicker call..